# How to sum then add up to the other column

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5

Need some help please, I want to sum the price in prodprice table and add it to a_cost,b_cost and c_cost in prodcost table where main_item is 00002 in the prodcomb, the 00002 has secondary_item which is 00001,now `00001 in prodbm in main_item have 2 secondary_item
00005 and 00006 these two have price in prodprice and I want to sum there price and add it a_cost,b_cost and c_cost .

the result look like this,the unitprice is compose of a_cost + b_cost + c_cost + sumprice.

```
+-----+-----------+
| qty | unitprice |
+-----+-----------+
| 2   | 23.50     |
+-----+-----------+
```

prodprice

```
+-------+------+
| item  | price| 
+-------+------+
| 00005 | 5.00 |
+-------+------+
| 00006 | 3.50 |
+-------+------+
```

prodbm

```
+-----------+----------------+
| main_item | secondary_item |
+-----------+----------------+
| 00001     | 00005          |
+-----------+----------------+
| 00001     | 00006          |
+-----------+----------------+
```

prodcomb

```
+-----------+----------------+-----+
| main_item | secondary_item | qty |
+-----------+----------------+-----+
| 00002     | 00001          | 2   |
+-----------+----------------+-----+
```

prodcost

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| item  | a_cost | b_cost | c_cost | m_cost|
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| 00001 | 5      | 5      | 5      | 6     |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Strawberry, I actually I am using sql-server for laravel5.2

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
 select d.qty, sum(a.price) + b.a_cost + b.b_cost + b.c_cost
 from prodprice as a 
 inner join prodcost as b on b.itme = c.main_item
 inner join prodbm as c c.secondary_item = a.item 
 inner join prodcomb as d on d.secondary_item = b.item
 group by a.item, d.qty
```

Comment: I will try your solution. I'll be back, can I use where prodcomb.main_item = 00002

Comment: How to include the quantity in prodcomb ?

Comment: Qty  added .. with inner join on prodcomb

Comment: Ok I'll try this, I'll back. Thank you

Comment: I have error in c.main_item "the mulitplier c.main_item could not be found"